# modificar elementos por checkbox checked

Tags: vue.js

Tengo un estado en pinia, que es un arreglo de objetos que contiene un id, un titulo y una url, este arreglo lo recorro con v-for en un componente y por cada uno muestro un input checkbox con una imagen correspondiente con la url del arreglo. A cada checkbox le agrego v-model,:value y un id que al dar click me agrega el id de cada checkbox al arreglo vacio, si esta checked agrega el id, si no lo esta, lo elimina, cuando el input checkbox este checked agregar alguna clase a la imagen para que la modifique , al no estarlo eliminar esta clase, como puedo hacer esto?

> Recorro el arreglo del store y muestro los checkbox y las imagenes

```
<div v-for="item in store.items" :key="store.id">
    <input 
        type="checkbox"
        :value="item.title"
        v-model="store.checkeds"
        :id="item.id"
    >

        <img 
          :src="item.url" 
          :alt="item.title" 
          width="30"
          height="30"
        >
  </div>
```

> Store

```
state: () => ({
   checkeds: [],
   items: [
     {
       "id": "1",
       "url": "../assets/imagen.svg",
       "title": "imagen"
     },
     {
       "id": "2",
       "url": "../assets/imagen2.svg",
       "title": "imagen2"
     },
     {
       "id": "3",
       "url": "../assets/imagen3.svg",
       "title": "imagen3"
     },
     {
       "id": "4",
       "url": "../assets/imagen4.svg",
       "title": "imagen4"
     },
     {
       "id": "5",
       "url": "../assets/imagen5.svg",
       "title": "imagen5"
     },
     {
       "id": "6",
       "url": "../assets/imagen6.svg",
       "title": "imagen6"
     },
   ]
})
```

Comment: No termino de entender. "con esto quiero que al estar checked o exista el id del checkbox en el arreglo, me afecte la imagen, si no, vuelva a su forma original". Podrías mejorar tu descripción del inconveniente para ayudarte, por favor.

Comment: acabo de modificar la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que insertas la clave title en `checkeds` para saber cual es la imagen elegida, puedes hacer uso de la misma para modificar el estilo de las imágenes, usando:

`includes()` *Determina si una matriz incluye un determinado elemento.*

`Style Bindings` *Enlace de estilos en línea de un elemento.*

Usando `<script setup>`.

```
import {nombreDeTuStore} from '../stores/ruta-de-tu-store'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
import { ref} from 'vue'

//storeToRefs para desestructurar estados.
const st = nombreDeTuStore()
const {items, checkeds} = storeToRefs(st)

//Estilos
const styles = ref({
  background: 'red', 
})
```

Para este ejemplo vinculo directamente a un objeto usando `:style` pero podría enlazar valores también: [Enlaces de clase y estilo vue 3](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html)

```
<template>
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <input 
        type="checkbox"
        :value="item.title"
        v-model="checkeds"
        :id="item.id"
    >

        <img 
          :src="item.url" 
          :alt="item.title" 
          width="120"
          height="120"
          :style=" checkeds.includes(item.title) ? styles : 'transparent'"
        >
  </div>
  {{checkeds}}
</template>
```

Con esto, cada ckeckbox al ser elegido inserta el titulo de la imagen referenciada al estado `checkeds`, y es usado para verificarse en el enlace de estilos y ser aplicado el estilo/clase necesaria a las imágenes.